# How handle loss with market maker bot?

Tags: binance, bot

i'm using a bot to do some market maker on exchange.

I still have one last issue, i don't know how to handle loss.

For example if price go down and my bot triggered buy just before the downtrend. I will have a sell order placed for eternety while the price doesn't pump.

Should i cancel this sell order ? Should i place it at lower and take loss ? Or just wait and hope that the price will pump at a moment ?

Thank for your help or suggestion !

Comment: That question isnt really fit for this stack, but the answer is yes. When you open a position you should have 2 sell orders, a take profit and a stop loss